# Uma cidade separada consulta sql

Tags: mysql, sql

Minha tabela de vendas marca: cidade para o qual foi feito a venda, data e hora da venda.
Gostaria de puxar todas as vendas ordenadas por data e hora, porém com uma cidade em específico separado.
Por exemplo:
Venda 12 - Brasilia - 2017-05-29 10:00:00
Venda 20 - Brasilia - 2017-05-29 11:00:00
Venda 31 - Brasilia - 2017-05-29 12:00:00

E em seguida todas as outras vendas de todas as outras cidades ordenadas por data.

Comment: "E em seguida todas as outras vendas ordenadas por data." da mesma cidade ou de todas as outras cidades?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simples, basta usar o *where* para a cidade desejada e *order by* para ordenar pela data se deseja selecionar dados apenas de uma cidade.

```
Select * from SuaTabela where colunaCidade = "Brasilia" order by colunaData
```

para selecionar todos os dados e ordenar primeiro por uma cidade especifica:

```
Select * from SuaTabela order by (colunaCidade = "Brasilia") desc,colunaData
```

Comment: De todas as outras cidades.

Comment: @PedroAugusto tente agora

Comment: Perfeito, obrigado !

Answer (score -2):

Tu vai precisar de duas consultas, uma com cidade='brasilia' e outra com cidade<>'brasilia'. E juntar as duas com UNION.

Comment: concordo com o uso de "union", porém a resposta poderia ter incluido o código por completo para resolver o problema

Comment: A solução do @Leo Longhi é muito melhor.